# CMakeLists.txt vs package.xml

Tags: ros

I've read this link: https://answers.ros.org/question/217475/cmakeliststxt-vs-packagexml/

But still, I can't understand very clearly.

When I try to compile ROS project with the command: `catkin_make --install`, how and when is the package.xml used? how and when is the CMakeLists.txt used? Both of them must be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding [CMakeLists.txt](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt), it

> is the input to the CMake build system for building software packages.

You can think of this file as simply being a list of the cmake build targets and commands for your specific package. It may help to read [this to get a general idea](https://cmake.org/overview/).

For [package.xml](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml), it

> defines properties about the package such as the package name, version numbers, authors, maintainers, and dependencies on other catkin packages.

**EDIT:** According to an answer in [How do I write package.xml?](https://answers.ros.org/question/202322/how-do-i-write-packagexml/) the package.xml is used during the install process to help resolve dependencies.

If you are missing any dependencies and they are not listed in the package.xml file before running `catkin_make --install`, then your build will either fail or not work as expected.

Comment: If Package.xml is not used by catkin_make to build or install, what is it used for? only for human reading?

Comment: @Yves, package.xml is used to resolve dependencies when installing. Aside from the installation process, the file can be used for human reading.